# Differential Equations (Applications)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A particle moves in a straight line with an acceleration that varies directly with the square of its velocity.  At time t=0, the particle passes a fixed point O with a velocity of $2ms^{-1}$.  A second later, the velocity of the particle has increased to $4ms^{-1}$.  By representing the velocity of the particle as v and its displacement from O as $x$ at any time t, find

a)v as a function of t
b)v as a function of x
c)x as a function of t.

I'm okay to solve the differential equations, but I'm weak to setting up the equations from this type of question. Can anyone guide me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $a$ varies directly with $v^2$ means $a = kv^2$ for some $k$

Answer (score 0):

we can set up the origin at $O$ and the positive direction as the same as the direction of the motion of the particle. let $v = \dot x = \frac{dx}{dt}$ represent the velocity of the particle. then we have $$\dot v = k v^2, x(0) = 0,  v(0) = 2, v(1) = 4.$$

now that the equations are set up, you can solve it.